# Want to create gridview which have 0 as starting value and it get change to 1 on litem selected and it also change back to 0 if same cell is selected

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclick

```
public class second extends ActionBarActivity 
{ 

    GridView gv;  //GridView declaration   

    String[] value1=value1=new String[]{"0","0","0","0","0"};
    String imc_met;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,value1);

        //Array is set in gridview gv.setAdapter(ad);

        //item click listener for gridview selected value
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                String value=value1[position];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

NOTE: So right now grid view show 5 times 0, i want a code which can change 0 to 1 if it is clicked and 1 to 0 if 1 is cilcked.

Comment: Have you tried any thing so far to toggle between the values 0 and 1?

Comment: I have no idea how to do so, so far i am able to get the selected cell value, now i need to change it, But i have no idea how.

Comment: Just search for android list view and how to updated it, use the same approach to update your value, you are almost there